# Problem With Adding Custom Styling to ReactJS Google Map

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I am trying to add custom styling to my google map on React JS, but I keep running into the same problem.

When I implement the styling(I have tried it in several ways) and launch my app the map disappears and instead I only have a white screen(however, the map shows when I run the default styling).

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper, InfoWindow, Marker } from 'google-maps-react';
 
const key = 'key'
 
export class MapContainer extends Component {
  state = {
    showingInfoWindow: false,  
    activeMarker: {},          
    selectedPlace: {},
    markers: [
      //Array of markers
    ],
  };
 
  onMarkerClick = (props, marker, e) =>
  this.setState({
    selectedPlace: props,
    activeMarker: marker,
    showingInfoWindow: true
  });
 
  onClose = props => {
    if (this.state.showingInfoWindow) {
      this.setState({
        showingInfoWindow: false,
        activeMarker: null
      });
    }
  };
 
  render() {
    return (
      <Map
        google={this.props.google}
        zoom={14}
        style={this.props.mapStyles}
        initialCenter={{ lat: 49.166590, lng: -123.133569 }}
      >
      {this.state.markers.map((marker, index) => (
        <Marker
          key={index} 
          onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
          name={marker.name}
          position={marker.position}
        />
      ))}
 
        <InfoWindow
          marker={this.state.activeMarker}
          visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
          onClose={this.onClose}
        >
          <div>
            <h4>{this.state.selectedPlace.name}</h4>
          </div>
        </InfoWindow>
      </Map>
    );
  }
}
 
MapContainer.defaultProps = {
  mapStyles: [
    {
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [
            {
                color: '#242f3e'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [
            {
                color: '#746855'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
        stylers: [
            {
                color: '#242f3e'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        featureType: 'administrative.land_parcel',
        elementType: 'labels',
        stylers: [
            {
                visibility: 'off'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        featureType: 'administrative.locality',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [
            {
                color: '#d59563'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        featureType: 'poi',
        elementType: 'labels.text',
        stylers: [
            {
                visibility: 'off'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        featureType: 'poi',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [
            {
                color: '#d59563'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        featureType: 'poi.business',
        stylers: [
            {
                visibility: 'off'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        featureType: 'poi.park',
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [
            {
                color: '#263c3f'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        featureType: 'poi.park',
        elementType: 'labels.text',
        stylers: [
            {
                visibility: 'off'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        featureType: 'poi.park',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [
            {
                color: '#6b9a76'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        featureType: 'road',
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [
            {
                color: '#38414e'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        featureType: 'road',
        elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
        stylers: [
            {
                color: '#212a37'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        featureType: 'road',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [
            {
                color: '#9ca5b3'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        featureType: 'road.highway',
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [
            {
                color: '#746855'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        featureType: 'road.highway',
        elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
        stylers: [
            {
                color: '#1f2835'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        featureType: 'road.highway',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [
            {
                color: '#f3d19c'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        featureType: 'road.local',
        elementType: 'labels',
        stylers: [
            {
                visibility: 'off'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        featureType: 'transit',
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [
            {
                color: '#2f3948'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        featureType: 'transit.station',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [
            {
                color: '#d59563'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        featureType: 'water',
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [
            {
                color: '#17263c'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        featureType: 'water',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [
            {
                color: '#515c6d'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        featureType: 'water',
        elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
        stylers: [
            {
                color: '#17263c'
            }
        ]
    }
]
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: key
})(MapContainer);
```

Been struggling with this for a couple hours, turned Google inside out for tutorials and followed many several times but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What does your Javascript console say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully implemented custom mapstyle using the syntax from the [google-maps-react library documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react#custom-map-style).

Here is my sample [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-swanson-hhq4g?file=/src/MapComponent.jsx). Make sure to change the value of the API key in the GoogleApiWrapper for the code to run. You can also use the [Google Maps Styling Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) to easily create styles for your map.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Map, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper } from "google-maps-react";

const mapStyle = [
  {
    elementType: "geometry",
    stylers: [
      {
        color: "#1d2c4d"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    elementType: "labels.text.fill",
    stylers: [
      {
        color: "#8ec3b9"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    elementType: "labels.text.stroke",
    stylers: [
      {
        color: "#1a3646"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "administrative.country",
    elementType: "geometry.stroke",
    stylers: [
      {
        color: "#4b6878"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "administrative.land_parcel",
    elementType: "labels.text.fill",
    stylers: [
      {
        color: "#64779e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "administrative.province",
    elementType: "geometry.stroke",
    stylers: [
      {
        color: "#4b6878"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "landscape.man_made",
    elementType: "geometry.stroke",
    stylers: [
      {
        color: "#334e87"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "landscape.natural",
    elementType: "geometry",
    stylers: [
      {
        color: "#023e58"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "poi",
    elementType: "geometry",
    stylers: [
      {
        color: "#283d6a"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "poi",
    elementType: "labels.text.fill",
    stylers: [
      {
        color: "#6f9ba5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "poi",
    elementType: "labels.text.stroke",
    stylers: [
      {
        color: "#1d2c4d"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "poi.park",
    elementType: "geometry.fill",
    stylers: [
      {
        color: "#023e58"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "poi.park",
    elementType: "labels.text.fill",
    stylers: [
      {
        color: "#3C7680"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "road",
    elementType: "geometry",
    stylers: [
      {
        color: "#304a7d"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "road",
    elementType: "labels.text.fill",
    stylers: [
      {
        color: "#98a5be"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "road",
    elementType: "labels.text.stroke",
    stylers: [
      {
        color: "#1d2c4d"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "road.highway",
    elementType: "geometry",
    stylers: [
      {
        color: "#2c6675"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "road.highway",
    elementType: "geometry.stroke",
    stylers: [
      {
        color: "#255763"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "road.highway",
    elementType: "labels.text.fill",
    stylers: [
      {
        color: "#b0d5ce"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "road.highway",
    elementType: "labels.text.stroke",
    stylers: [
      {
        color: "#023e58"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "transit",
    elementType: "labels.text.fill",
    stylers: [
      {
        color: "#98a5be"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "transit",
    elementType: "labels.text.stroke",
    stylers: [
      {
        color: "#1d2c4d"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "transit.line",
    elementType: "geometry.fill",
    stylers: [
      {
        color: "#283d6a"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "transit.station",
    elementType: "geometry",
    stylers: [
      {
        color: "#3a4762"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "water",
    elementType: "geometry",
    stylers: [
      {
        color: "#0e1626"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "water",
    elementType: "labels.text.fill",
    stylers: [
      {
        color: "#4e6d70"
      }
    ]
  }
];

export class MapContainer extends Component {
  _mapLoaded(mapProps, map) {
    map.setOptions({
      styles: mapStyle
    });
  }

  render() {
    const coords = { lat: -21.805149, lng: -49.0921657 };
    return (
      <Map
        style={this.mapStyle}
        google={this.props.google}
        zoom={7}
        initialCenter={coords}
        onReady={(mapProps, map) => this._mapLoaded(mapProps, map)}
      >
        <Marker position={coords} />
      </Map>
    );
  }
}
export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY"
})(MapContainer);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I stg I did it that way before and it didn't work. I must've been missing something before because it works now. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome! Also, make sure to use a correct Json for your mapstyles. I can see that your Json has labels.text>visibility:off but you still put labels.text.fill>color. You can use the Styling Wizard to have a good and clean Json style.

Comment: I will do that, thank you! I have another quick question, is there anyway to change the styling of the InfoWindows? (Font size, colors etc.) I've tried adding classNames and using CSS but it doesn't seem to work. From what I read on Google it seems that there isn't much flexibility for InfoWindow styling, is that right?

Comment: For infoWindow, you can  override the values of the .gm-style .gm-style-iw as stated [here](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/issues/291#issuecomment-443115389). Here's a [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-nightingale-lopjg) implemented in the code.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use default props for this. The custom Style json data should be a default props. Here is a working solution :**

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper } from "google-maps-react";
    export class MapContainer extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <Map
            google={this.props.google}
            zoom={14}
            styles={this.props.mapStyles}
            initialCenter={{
              lat: 51.1657,
              lng: 10.4515,
            }}
          />
        );
      }
    }
   //this is how you make the style a defaultprops for the component. 
   //best way is to add the design json data in a separte line
   // go here for different Map style and customization : http://snazzymaps.com/
    MapContainer.defaultProps = {
      mapStyles: [
        {
            "featureType": "all",
            "elementType": "labels",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "on"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "all",
            "elementType": "labels.text",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "on"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "all",
            "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "saturation": 36
                },
                {
                    "color": "#111111"
                },
                {
                    "lightness": 60
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "all",
            "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "on"
                },
                {
                    "color": "#000000"
                },
                {
                    "lightness": 16
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "all",
            "elementType": "labels.icon",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "off"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "administrative",
            "elementType": "geometry.fill",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "color": "#000000"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "administrative",
            "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "color": "#000000"
                },
                {
                    "lightness": 17
                },
                {
                    "weight": 1.2
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "administrative",
            "elementType": "labels",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "on"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "administrative",
            "elementType": "labels.text",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "on"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "administrative.country",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "simplified"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "administrative.country",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "simplified"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "administrative.country",
            "elementType": "labels.text",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "simplified"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "administrative.province",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "on"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "administrative.locality",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "simplified"
                },
                {
                    "saturation": "-100"
                },
                {
                    "lightness": "30"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "on"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "on"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "landscape",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "simplified"
                },
                {
                    "gamma": "0.00"
                },
                {
                    "lightness": "74"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "landscape",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "color": "#000000"
                },
                {
                    "lightness": 20
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "landscape",
            "elementType": "labels",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "on"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "landscape",
            "elementType": "labels.text",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "on"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "lightness": "3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "poi",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "on"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "poi",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "color": "#000000"
                },
                {
                    "lightness": 40
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "poi",
            "elementType": "labels",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "on"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "poi",
            "elementType": "labels.text",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "on"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "road",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "simplified"
                },
                {
                    "color": "#424242"
                },
                {
                    "lightness": "-61"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "road",
            "elementType": "labels",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "on"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "road",
            "elementType": "labels.text",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "on"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "road.highway",
            "elementType": "geometry.fill",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "color": "#000000"
                },
                {
                    "lightness": 17
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "road.highway",
            "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "color": "#000000"
                },
                {
                    "lightness": 29
                },
                {
                    "weight": 0.2
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "road.arterial",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "color": "#000000"
                },
                {
                    "lightness": 18
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "road.local",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "color": "#000000"
                },
                {
                    "lightness": 16
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "transit",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "color": "#2a2727"
                },
                {
                    "lightness": "-61"
                },
                {
                    "saturation": "-100"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "transit",
            "elementType": "labels",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "on"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "water",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "color": "#000000"
                },
                {
                    "lightness": 17
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "water",
            "elementType": "labels",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "on"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "water",
            "elementType": "labels.text",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "on"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    };
    export default GoogleApiWrapper({
      apiKey: "your API key goes here",
    })(MapContainer);
```